# Nominatim application error PHP

Tags: php, curl, openstreetmap, php-curl, nominatim

I have PHP app which sends url request for  geocoding as:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=33&lon=34&addressdetails=1
```

when I copy to browser returns XML respond. When same url sending from PHP file have response as:

```
<html><head><title>Bandwidth limit exceeded</title></head><body><h1>Bandwidth limit exceeded</h1><p>You have been temporarily blocked because you have been overusing OSM's geocoding service or because you have not provided sufficient identification of your application. This block will be automatically lifted after a while. Please take the time and adapt your scripts to reduce the number of requests and make sure that you send a valid UserAgent or Referer.</p><p>For more information, consult the <a href="http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy">usage policy</a> for the OSM Nominatim server.</body></head>
```

that request is sending every 5 minutes which is not violating 1 sec min. request restriction. How can avoid to have that error message?

```
// Send to nomintaim server reverse geocoding request 
    $url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=" . $loc['lat'] . "&lon=" . $loc['lng']. "&addressdetails=1";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: "that you send a valid UserAgent or Referer" , please add the php code you use

Comment: I added the code  to main question

Comment: AFAIK curl won't set up UserAgent or Referer header for you that shoud be included by you, "you have not provided sufficient identification of your application" have you got any code for identify yourself for api?

Comment: You have already exceeded the bandwidth limit. Wait until you get unblocked, then try again. Read the [usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy), alternatively [install your own Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) or use a [third-party Nominatim provider](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers).

Comment: no any identify codes, first time using nominatim, i am new in php

Comment: i did not exceeded the bandwidth limit its happened after first try

Comment: Seems like you have to use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` for setting the user-agent with PHP cURL.

Comment: scai- works excellent now as your answer

Answer (score 3):

You should use CURLOPT_USERAGENT & CURLOPT_REFERER like this :

```
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
```

Comment: Defintely its working! Nominatim faking response with 404 if no `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` provided.